# Memory leaks on phasset.requestContentEditingInput

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a Memory LEAK at requestContentEditingInput.

So I have an array of PHAssets(Images). What i am trying is to check if meta-data (EXIF) exists for an image by iterating the images one by one, and later on i am editing that EXIF and saving that image onto the disk. For reading the content

```
 asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { (contentEditingInput, info) in

}
```

This is the line causing 15 leaks according to instrument. Even if i remove everything from inside the block, the leak is happening when requestContentEditingInput is called. When i comment this method, i don't see any leaks, which concludes that the leak is happening at this line (and not inside it's block.

Following is the complete code:

```
 let assetWithAlbum = assetsFromPhotoLibrary.remove(at: 0)
    let asset = assetWithAlbum.phAsset
    imageCountRemaining -= 1
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true //Comment out this line to process iCloud Photos last
    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { (contentEditingInput, info) in
        if info["PHContentEditingInputResultIsInCloudKey"] as? Int == 1 {
            log.ln("Content Editing Input could not be created for asset \(asset.localIdentifier) result is in the Cloud!")/
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
            return
        }
        guard let safeContentEditingInput = contentEditingInput else {
            log.ln("Content Editing Input could not be created for asset \(asset.localIdentifier)")/
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            guard let imageURL = safeContentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL, let fullImage = CIImage(contentsOf: imageURL) else {
               
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
                return
            }
            var imageProperties = fullImage.properties
            imageProperties.removeValue(forKey: "Orientation")
            guard let exifProperties = imageProperties["{Exif}"] as? [String: Any] else {
           
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .containsNoValidEXIFInformation, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
                return
            }
            

      
            let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
            //requestOptions.isSynchronous = true //This blocks the calling thread and since we are already on a background thread we are ok
            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: self.targetSize ?? PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions) { (result, info) in
                guard let imageIsDegraded = info?[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as? Bool else {
                  
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
                    return
                }
                guard let resultingImage = result else {
                   
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
                    return
                }
                if !imageIsDegraded {
                    //Process EXIF information next and store it on a JPG representation of the image
                    guard let jpegImage = resultingImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.85) else {
                      
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputFailed, object: self, userInfo: ["AssetID": asset.localIdentifier])
                        return
                    }
                    
                    let formattedLocalID = self.format(requestID: asset.localIdentifier)
                    self.saveImageWithProperties(data: jpegImage, filename: formattedLocalID,albumName: assetWithAlbum.albumTitle, properties: imageProperties as NSDictionary) { (jpegWithExif, fileURL) in
                       
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .contentEditingInputComplete, object: fileURL) //Want an observer?
                        self.imageQueue.updateValue(fileURL.absoluteString, forKey: formattedLocalID)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on the leak , or is there any other way through which i can access the Exif and content of PHAsset image ?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was requestContentEditingInput. This is costly call. As i was iterating through an array of PHAssets images, this function call was made several times for every asset index. In my case, i only needed meta-data (Exif) of the image. If you just need meta-data of the image consider calling requestImageDataAndOrientation which is more background friendly & less costly.

This is how you can fetch Meta-Data from PHAsset.

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: phAsset, options: requestOption,resultHandler: {(data,string,imageOrientation, dictionary) in
            if let data = data{
                
                let metaData = fetchPhotoMetadata(data: data)
                guard let _metaData = metaData else
                {
                    print("No valid data found for the image id =  \(asset.localIdentifier)")/
                    return
                }
                if(!hasValidMetaData(properties: _metaData))
                {
                    print("Image contains no EXIF information and will be removed from queue: \(asset.localIdentifier)")/
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    //Resize here 
                }
                
            }
        })

 func fetchPhotoMetadata(data: Data) -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let selectedImageSourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil),
        let imagePropertiesDictionary = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(selectedImageSourceRef, 0, nil) as? [String: Any] else {
            return nil
    }
    return imagePropertiesDictionary
}    


 func hasValidMetaData(properties: [String: Any]) -> Bool {
        if(properties["{Exif}"] != nil){
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Did you stick with this in the end?
I'm having the exact same issue where requestContentEditingInput just increases the memory usage.
But the problem with PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation is for newly imported RAW images it fails entirely and after you give the device a minute or so to process the RAW files, the code will then work but will not return the same amount of EXIF info as requestContentEditingInput.